# Різниця між словами "супровід" та супроводження"

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, віддієслівні-іменники

Чи існує різниця у вживанні слів **супровід** та **супроводження**?

У словнику СУМ таке тлумачення: *[**Супровід**](http://sum.in.ua/s/suprovid)*

До слова ***супроводження*** знайшла два значення:

1) *СУПРОВО́ДЖЕННЯ, я, сер.
1. Дія за значенням супроводити.
2. Те саме, що супровід 5. З того часу, як почалися бої в Будапешті, гармати супроводження йшли поряд штурмових груп (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 262).*

2) *[Супроводження](http://www.marazm.org.ua/document/termin/index.php?file=%D1%F3%EF%F0%EE%E2%EE%E4%E6%E5%ED%ED%FF.txt) - заходи забезпечення збереження і захисту від розкрадань матеріальних цінностей, а також заходи безпеки пасажирів і таких цінностей в контрольованих зонах авіапідприємств.*

Comment: Див. також: [«Як бути з віддієслівними іменниками на -ння, -ття?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3084). Хоча те запитання, звісно, може не враховувати якісь специфічні нюанси щодо конкретної пари слів. (І станов на цей момент воно досі не має відповіді.)

Comment: Другий приклад - це означення для конкретного документа, так само як у договорі купівлі продажу пишуть "Петро Петрович (далі ПОКУПЕЦЬ)" і це не означає що Петро Петрович в українській мові це завжди синонім слова покупець. У посиланні вказано що це цитата з "Правил супроводження в контрольованих зонах авіапідприємств матеріальних цінностей і пасажирів", відповідно у цих правилах треба пояснити що означає "супроводження" в контексті цього документа, а саме, що пасажири в аеропорту повинні бути у безпеці, а вантажі - не пошкоджені та не розкрадені.

Comment: (продовження) Схожий приклад - тлумачення "перевага — право на першочерговий рух стосовно інших учасників дорожнього руху", взяте з "Правил дорожнього руху, Загальні положення". Можна порівняти це означення з означенням [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/perevagha).

Answer (score 4):

Так існує:

- **супроводження**

  Позначає дїю [тривалої] дїї, що є звичаєвим для подібних віддїєваних іменників з наростком **ння**. Загалом так зазначає і СУМ.
- **супровід**

  Позначає живу чи неживу річ, котра відображає дїю. Про всяк зазначу, що за цією річчю не утворюється дїя, бо тоді був би наросток **ка**.

Наразі це звучить складно, оскільки [мовознищення](http://ji.lviv.ua/n35texts/kocherha.htm) чуттєво спотворило [наростків](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky), але спробую пояснити прикладами чи порівняннями. Тому наразі вони є **сутямами** в більшості випадках, але коли цїкава різниця, то буде наступне:

---

- **ø**

  - *гра* — це річ дїї;
  - *добрий супровід* — похвала речі дії, не обовʼязково при цьому чогось робити.
- **ння**

  - *грання* — це дїя дїї;
  - *добре супроводження* — похвала дїї дїї, він зробив *добре дію*.

Детальнїший приклад на основі чогось: *знаємо, що є якісна відома музіка, де грають двоє, тому ми вже знаємо, що супровід якісний, але треба для цього майстерні супровідники; прийшли на виставу, але нам не сподобалося, бо супроводження було геть погане, бо майстер захворів, а замість нього зʼявився новачок чи хтось непідготовлений.*

Про всяк також додам і **ка**, оскільки заувагу зробив:

- **ка**

  - *іграшка*, хоча доречніше *забавка* проти *забава* — річ, котра робить дїю;
  - *супровідка* — уявна річ, котра супроводжує вас, тому аби ввічливіше назвати жінку, котра супроводжує вас, бажано звати *супровідницею*, тобто від наростка *ник* в *ниця*, що є можливим тут, порівняйте з [*провідниця*](http://sum.in.ua/s/providnycja); хоча, так, *ка* може позначати і деякі жіночі звання, а *(ни)ця* навпаки щось неживе чи взагалі уявне.

Answer (score 0):

Згідно зі [Словопедією](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53409/27001.html) та СУМом - це слова-синоніми, тому різниці між ними немає - "Супроводження - те саме, що супровід" (СУМ), однак краще надати перевагу слову "супровід".

Comment: Якщо слова десь позначені як синоніми, це не обов'язково означає, що вони **повні** синоніми (бувають **часткові** синоніми). І СУМ-11 якраз надає цим словам різне значення: «супровід» використовується в значеннях «дія за значенням _супровождувати 1, 3, 4, 5_ (але не _2_)» і ще 4 інших значеннях, у той час як «супроводження» використовується в значеннях «дія за значенням _супровождувати 1, 2, 3, 4, 5_» і «= _супровід 5_» (але не «_супровід 2, 3, 4_»).

Comment: Однак з міткою «we're looking for long answers», що причепили до Вашої відповіді, незгоден. По-моєму, короткі відповіді — це добре, якщо вони при цьому точні (тобто лаконічні, а не неповні).